# Disable text selection bar for Android webview but keep text selection handles (Xamarin)

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin for Android but this could equally apply to the Android JAVA SDK.
I have a webview and the user can select text on the web page using the built in Android OS handles. I want to disable the text selection action bar which appears on long press but not disable the text selection handles used to do the selection.

I have tried overriding the OnSelectionStart method but this did not have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Since Android 6.0 introduces [Text selection](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html), i face the same issue. Thanks to [paolo.camitini](http://www.mzan.com/article/36088057-android-webview-prevent-text-selection-actionmode-actionbar.shtml), i found the . To resolve your issue, you have to override methods **startActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback)** and **public ActionMode startActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback, int type)** (from SDK 23). Here is my implementation:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class EpubWebView extends WebView {
    public EpubWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public EpubWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public EpubWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public EpubWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, boolean privateBrowsing) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, privateBrowsing);
    }

    @Override
    public ActionMode startActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback) {
        return new ActionMode() {
            @Override
            public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
            }

            @Override
            public void setTitle(int resId) {
            }

            @Override
            public void setSubtitle(CharSequence subtitle) {
            }

            @Override
            public void setSubtitle(int resId) {
            }

            @Override
            public void setCustomView(View view) {
            }

            @Override
            public void invalidate() {
            }

            @Override
            public void finish() {
            }

            @Override
            public Menu getMenu() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getTitle() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getSubtitle() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getCustomView() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public ActionMode startActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback, int type) {
        return new ActionMode() {
            @Override
            public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
            }

            @Override
            public void setTitle(int resId) {
            }

            @Override
            public void setSubtitle(CharSequence subtitle) {
            }

            @Override
            public void setSubtitle(int resId) {
            }

            @Override
            public void setCustomView(View view) {
            }

            @Override
            public void invalidate() {
            }

            @Override
            public void finish() {
            }

            @Override
            public Menu getMenu() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getTitle() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getSubtitle() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getCustomView() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```